# Sphinx delta index config

Tags: mysql, sphinx

Following doc from: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.6.html#delta-updates

I'm confused about the purpose of `sph_counter` Is it used to identify an index table, so if I were to use a second index with delta the `sph_counter` for it would simply be 2?

**Main source becomes?**

```
sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 2, MAX(id) FROM table_2
```

**Delta source becomes?**

```
sql_query = SELECT id, title, body FROM table_2 \
        WHERE id>( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=2
```

Thank you,that is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly. The first column of the table `sph_counter` is a counter identifier. You could also define it as a varchar column and store the table name into it.

In your case, the value doesn't have to be 2 - it can be any value you want, as long as it is different for each table.

Comment: You're too late buddy I've already answer my question with EMPIRICAL data